Print and Download React component to the full size of a paper
I built a nice react component in the proprotions of 8.5:11 to match a standard letter page and am now trying to let the user both download and print it from the browser at full scale. Been trying to use the html-to-image library to convert it to an SVG first but I can't seem to resize it and it's way to small as the component is 340px by 440px.
How would you do it? I don't mind much on the format of the download, png, jpg, even svg is fine.
Bonus points if there's a way to adjust it to say 95% to avoid the printer cutting off the edges when printing.

I need the print to be high quality also, not pixelized due to scaling this up

Have you checked https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/?

I believe html-to-image is built on top of that

You can use the react-to-print library, it will allow you to open the print table and print the html template as pdf or print directly, it will print the content perfectly
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
       content: () => componentRef?.current,
       documentTitle: 'title',
});


I gave this a shot but it has the same scale issue and also an additional issue with the text in my component being shifted (guessing some CSS is missing when capturing the component)

Can you post a screenshot?

Please set the component to the correct ratio you need, for example A4:
<div
   ref={ref}
   style={{
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    height: '29.7cm',
    width: '21cm',
    fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
    paddingLeft: '1.6cm',
    paddingTop: '1.2cm',
    paddingRight: '1.6cm',
    paddingBottom: '1.2cm',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    fontSize: '12pt'
   }}
  >

